# What options do I have if I want to share data/attributes among Ruby Objects?

Tags: ruby, class, object, global

There are actually 2 cases here: 1)Objects are of the same type (for instance all are SomeClass objects), 2)Objects are not of the same type.

I am mostly interested in case 1. I tried to implement this using class variables but I read all over the internet to never use class variables (which I agree partially). What other ways are there to implement the same functionality?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for, but a commonly used alternative to class variables is instance variables on a class.

Comment: instance variable are not shared among classes but instead each class has its own instance variables. I want a way that when I say self.foo, I get the same result in every object. Mixins are not an alternative either as they cannot be initialized.

Comment: The warnings about using class variables are about not abusing them. There are proper uses for them, and maybe this is one of them depending upon your application. They do exist for a reason and aren't "totally banned". They are, essentially, variables global to all instances of the class. So they should be used with care.

Comment: Many structures would work. Please describe more about what you are trying to do, and please show some code that you have tried and explain where you are stuck. See http://www.sscce.org/ Also, it would help to understand whether the shared data is between all objects of same class, or only specific chosen ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have data shared by all objects in the class, you can use either class variables or class instance variables.

Class variables are shared in the class hierarchy. This can have side effects that might break your expectations, as demonstrated in this example:

```
class A
  @@common_data = :x

  def common_computation
    @@common_data
  end
end

class B < A
  @@common_data = :y
end

A.new.common_computation
# => y
B.new.common_computation
# => y
```

Class instance variables avoids that problem.

```
class A
  class << self
    attr_accessor :common_data
  end

  def common_computation
    self.class.common_data
  end

  self.common_data = :x
end

class B < A
  self.common_data = :y
end

A.new.common_computation
# => x
B.new.common_computation
# => y
```

---

You can use modules and mixins in order to share functionality and data.

```
module CommonFunctionality
  attr_writer :common_data

  def common_computation
    # use @common_data
  end
end

class A
  include CommonFunctionality
end

class B
  include CommonFunctionality
end

a = A.new
a.common_data = :x
a.common_computation
a.is_a? B                         # => false
a.kind_of? CommonFunctionality    # => true

b = B.new
b.common_data = :y
b.common_computation
b.is_a? A                         # => false
b.kind_of? CommonFunctionality    # => true
```

Comment: Thanks! But I think you share functionality, not actual data. In essence I want to achieve what class variables do but in a more elegant way.

Comment: @Filippos, you can share both if you need to. Any instance variable accessed by the methods in the module will be shared. Anyway, I think I know what you mean. I will edit my answer.